# How to make a language switcher in main menu for Drupal8

Tags: menu, drupal-8

Here is my problem on Drupal8. I have 3 languages in a website. In the future new languages can be installed.
I wanted to put a language switcher in the main menu.

My first try was to add a menu item with the UI. Like "Chinese". But it's impossible to state the language prefix doing like that. Also that means it won't update automatically if a language is added or removed from Drupal.

Second try :

```
$item = \Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent::create([
    'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/zh-hans/'],
    'title' => 'Chinese',
    'menu_name' => 'main',
]);
$item->save();
```

It adds a new item to the main menu but it won't take the language prefix. Anyway this is not a dynamic solution cause you have to rebuild the menu when language will be added or removed. Also the order of the languages will be set once and for all... I prefer to have the current language at the top so that depends in which language you are at this moment.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I achieved language switcher links (for French) in a Drupal menu.
This code can be catered to your specific needs.

<my_module>.links.menu.yml:

```
<my_module>.switch:
  class: Drupal\<my_module>\Plugin\Menu\MenuLanguageLink
  menu_name: main
  options:
    attributes:
      hreflang: 'fr'
```

Change "menu_name" to your Drupal menu.
Change "hreflang" to your language code.

src/Plugin/Menu/MenuLanguageLink.php:

```
namespace Drupal\<my_module>\Plugin\Menu;

use Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkBase;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class MenuLanguageLink extends MenuLinkBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /** @var array Available languages */
  protected $languages = [];

  /** @var Drupal\Core\Language\Language */
  protected $defaultLanguage;

  /** @var Drupal\Core\Language\Language */
  protected $currentLanguage;

  /** @var Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch */
  protected $currentRouteMatch;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager,
    CurrentRouteMatch $current_route_match
  ) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->languages = $language_manager->getLanguages();
    $this->defaultLanguage = $language_manager->getDefaultLanguage();
    $this->currentLanguage = $language_manager->getCurrentLanguage();
    $this->currentRouteMatch = $current_route_match;
  }

  /**
   * Dependency injection.
   */
  public static function create(
    ContainerInterface $container,
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition
  ) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('language_manager'),
      $container->get('current_route_match')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function updateLink(array $new_definition_values, $persist) {
    return $this->pluginDefinition;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getOptions() {
    $options = parent::getOptions();
    $langcode = $options['attributes']['hreflang'];
    $langcode_default = $this->defaultLanguage->getId();

    if ($langcode_default === $this->currentLanguage->getId()) {
      if (isset($this->languages[$langcode])) {
        $options += ['language' => $this->languages[$langcode]];
      }
    }
    else {
      $options += ['language' => $this->languages[$langcode_default]];
      $options['attributes']['hreflang'] = $langcode_default;
    }

    return $options; 
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getTitle() {
    $langcode = $this->getOptions()['attributes']['hreflang'];
    $langcode_default = $this->defaultLanguage->getId();
    if ($langcode_default === $this->currentLanguage->getId()) {
      return $this->languages[$langcode]->getName();
    }
    else {
      return $this->languages[$langcode_default]->getName();
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getRouteName() {
    return $this->currentRouteMatch->getRouteName();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getRouteParameters() {
    return $this->currentRouteMatch->getRawParameters()->all();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getDescription() {
    return $this->t('Switch language');
  }

}
```

The trick is setting the 'language' option in getOptions().

Comment: This code properly links to the French translation of an English node. But once on the French node, it would be nice to be able to get back to the English node. Providing this would make this solution complete.

Comment: @Bisonbleu edited MenuLanguageLink.php to include link back to default language.

Comment: Almost perfect! However; I can only see this menu item when I'm authenticated as administrator. I can't see the item as an anonymous user or other authenticated users. Is there any way to make this work for other authenticated and non-authenticated users?

Comment: @GoingDrupal looks like using "<current>" as the route_name causes issues with permissions.  User needs the "Link to any page" permission.  Not good.  I will update my answer with a workaround shortly.  Short answer: implement getRouteName() and getRouteParameters() in MenuLanguageLink.php using current_route_match service.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to GregCube. I also created a module that adds Language links to Main menu, language links always point to Front page.

I created module 'helpers' and placed 3 files there:

**listing of helpers.info.yml:**

```
name: 'My Helpers'
type: module
description: 'My helpsers'
# core: 8.x

core_version_requirement: ^8.8 || ^9
#dependencies:
#  - 'drupal:system (>= 8.8)'

version: '8.x-1.0'
datestamp: 1548970384
```

**listing of helpers.links.menu.yml:**

```
helpers.switch:
  class: Drupal\helpers\Plugin\Menu\MenuLanguageLink
  menu_name: main
  options:
    attributes:
      hreflang: 'ru'

helpers.switch:
  class: Drupal\helpers\Plugin\Menu\MenuLanguageLink
  menu_name: main
  options:
    attributes:
      hreflang: 'en'
```

**listing of src/Plugin/Menu/MenuLanguageLink.php:**

```
<?php

/*
  Add menu links to a language Front page
  options: hreflang
  do not create a link if hreflang langcode does not exist
  From https://stackoverflow.com/a/51005631/6851396
*/

namespace Drupal\helpers\Plugin\Menu;

use Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkBase;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;
//use Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

class MenuLanguageLink extends MenuLinkBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /** @var array Available languages */
  protected $languages = [];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager
  ) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->languages = $language_manager->getLanguages();
    $this->url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<front>');
  }

  /**
   * Dependency injection.
   */
  public static function create(
    ContainerInterface $container,
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition
  ) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('language_manager')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function updateLink(array $new_definition_values, $persist) {
    return $this->pluginDefinition;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getOptions() {
    $options = parent::getOptions();
    $langcode = $options['attributes']['hreflang'];

    if (isset($this->languages[$langcode])) {
      $options += ['language' => $this->languages[$langcode]];
    }

    return $options; 
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getTitle() {
    $langcode = $this->getOptions()['attributes']['hreflang'];
    return $this->languages[$langcode]->getName();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getRouteName() {
    return $this->url->getRouteName();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getRouteParameters() {
    return $this->url->getRouteParameters();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getDescription() {
    $langcode = $this->getOptions()['attributes']['hreflang'];
    return $this->languages[$langcode]->getName();
  }

}
```

here how it works
[language switcher in main menu, links to language front page always](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWXrM.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow Drupal's core language switcher code:

```
core/modules/language/src/Plugin/Block/LanguageBlock.php
```

First make sure to use PathMatcherInterface and LanguageManagerInterface

```
use Drupal\Core\Path\PathMatcherInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;
```

Then see get list of language links (lines 88 and 90):

```
$route_name = $this->pathMatcher->isFrontPage() ? '<front>' : '<current>';

$links = $this->languageManager->getLanguageSwitchLinks($type, Url::fromRoute($route_name));
```

Comment: I already looked into the language switcher but that's not really what I'm looking for. I want to put the thing into the main menu of Drupal in a dynamic way. The problem is not really to get the links. It's to find a way to include these links into the main menu in a dynamic way.